# Insert multiple records of a same table Yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to insert same record in one table. I have only one input array in the below form but i want to save multiple time record for `label input  array`.
my form is

```
<div class="surveys-questions-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?php

        if(isset($_GET['option_id']) and $_GET['option_id'] > 0)
            $id= $_GET['option_id'];
        else 
            $id= $model->option_id;
        echo $form->field($model, 'question_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => $id])->label(false);
    ?>

   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="question_wrapper">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([ 'text' => 'Text', 'numbers' => 'Numbers', 'date' => 'Date', 'texarea' => 'Texarea', 'checkbox' => 'Checkbox', 'radio' => 'Radio', 'rating' => 'Rating', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>
        <div id="add_more_field">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'label[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
                echo Html::a('Add more', 'javascript:void(0);', [
                    'id' => 'surveys-questions-new-button', 
                    'class' => 'pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs'
                ])
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
     </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

and controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new QuestionsOptions();

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->option_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Give me the following error when i try to submit form.

```
Label must be a string.
```

My $_POST array

```
  Array
(
    [_csrf-backend] => LXBhajI3YVpOIikeRWYHYkNCAD4Kb1ZrQzwER21GL2MdCTgkWm5ZDQ==
    [QuestionsOptions] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 47
            [type] => numbers
            [label] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Label1
                    [1] => Label2
                    [2] => Labe3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: can you please share the print_r result so that i get some idea about you posted data then i can guide you

Comment: @Dani thanks a lot. I have modified my question you can see in last of the post array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save multiple record use loop i suggest you to use foreach loop it is best

```
    public function actionCreate()
 {
      $model = new QuestionsOptions();

     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
           if(sizeof(array_filter($_POST['QuestionsOptions']['label'])) > 0){
             foreach($_POST['QuestionsOptions']['label'] as $key => $row){
                  $model->setIsNewRecord(true);
                  $model->id = null;
                  $model->label = $row;
                  $model->save();
             } 
          }
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->option_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @thank you so much. But one more thing how i will deal when I update them.

Comment: Working very fine thanks you. You can see in my code i create label filed with jquery clone method. If i click 2 time it add more button then 2 extra label will append. This means that 3 rows will be insert  in database. Now how i show these record in update form

Comment: @coder .. post a proper new answer ..   with  a clear description of yours need ..

Comment: I have created a proper question @scaisEdge. do not mind please you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417814/how-to-update-dynamic-field-in-yii2

Comment: This is a very bad way to do it. it will take more than minute if you have hunderds of rows.